# When to use Java Reflection API and when not to

Tags: java, parsing, reflection

I am trying to develop a parser in Java. It is for a game that will communicate with the parser via std in and std out. I am trying to create the parser to be very extendable and easy to use for anyone.

The goal is to run a customizable "script" on a server. The parser will keep track of everything the server sends it, and can also respond whenever necessary.

This means I will have to map many commands from the server to different events in the parser. In PHP, I know that you can easily call a variable function, which it seems is impossible to do in Java without using the Reflection API.

Let me start with an example input to the parser. `GAME_TIME 10` would be sent to the parser to update the current state of the game timer to 10.

I plan on creating a library of sorts that would handle basic things about the server, such as, how many players are currently online. The goal of the library is to make scripting these customized servers easier for server administrators.

Now when I approached this problem first, I had the idea to create a `HashMap<String, String[]>` that would map the name of the command to an array of the argument types. For example,
`map.put("GAME_TIME", new String[]{"time:int"});` The problem that arose with this is that after receiving the command in some form, how do I act upon the data?

One solution I came up with was to simply have a large switch statement that would match the commands and then call a method from there, but that renders the map pointless and would be a lot messier.

I know there is a way to use reflection to call a method from its name, but I am not sure if that is an appropriate solution here, it would definitely look prettier and make the code much shorter (unless I am missing something).

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the switch method way I currently have (and dislike).

```
public class Parser {

    public List<ServerEventReceiver> receivers = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addReceiver(ServerEventReceiver ser) {
        receivers.add(ser);
    }

    public void removeReceiver(ServerEventReceiver ser) {
        receivers.remove(ser);
    }

    public void parse(String command, String... args) {
        switch(command) {
            case "GAME_TIME":
                /**
                 * Allow any number of receivers to listen to the game_time event
                 */
                for(ServerEventReceiver ser: receivers)
                    ser.game_time(args[0]);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

The overall goal would be to allow a custom script to implement some class with a lot of server event methods (empty) in which they can override any of them they want to receive data from.

Comment: You can't use a switch statement with strings.

Comment: Huh. Apparently it does work with compile-time constants. In any case, switch is rarely the best answer. Look up Replace Conditional with Polymorphism, which is essentially what my answer recommends.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is to abstract the commands into a class with `name` and `execute` methods, then keep a `Map<String, Command>` that lets you look up the object by name. This promotes modularity (each class does one thing) and extensibility (just add more classes).

Comment: Would that mean there would be an entire class for each command?

Comment: classes are very lightweight. In fact a reference to a class takes up just as much memory as a reference to a string. In the end of the day this solution will probably take up less memory. Not that it would matter - Readable clean code is always to prefer over slight or imagined performance gains.

Comment: But is Reflection not very readable if done correctly? It would definitely reduce the amount of code needed.

Comment: @Tristan It's slower, more error-prone, and more difficult to read because of the defensiveness and exception handling required. This sort of case, where you have a bunch of similar pieces that respond to a particular input (the command line arguments) is exactly what interfaces were invented for.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if this would be an excellent use case for lambdas (in 1.8).

```
Map<String,Consumer<String[]>> c2f = new HashMap<>();
Consumer<String[]> printer = (strings) -> {
    System.out.println("string:" + strings[0]);
};
c2f.put( "print", printer );
```

And to invoke:

```
String command = ...;;
String[] data = ...;
c2f.get( command ).accept( data );
```

It's very powerful, you can combine it with generics...

Beats reflection, as it is typesafe.